# Selection in TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, tableview, uitableview

On selection of tableviewcell, i am change color of tableviewcell.
when i select cell on tableViewCell and scroll some other cell also selected.[image]

after scroll the other cell also affected

[image]

this is my code

```
static NSString *identifier = @"TBDCreateGamePlayerCell";

TBDCreateGamePlayerCell *playerCell = (TBDCreateGamePlayerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TBDCreateGamePlayerCell"];

if (!playerCell) {
    NSLog(@"creating a new cell : %d",row);
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TBDCreateGamePlayerCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    playerCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


}
```

Comment: since cells are reused you have to set selected/not selected whenever you reuse one.

Comment: How are you changing selection color ?

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];


- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    TBDCreateGamePlayerCell *cell=(TBDCreateGamePlayerCell *)recognizer.view;
   }

Answer (score 0):

You must implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Inside this method change the cell background back to the default color.

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:):

> **Discussion**
>
> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before
>   it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to
>   customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives
>   the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier
>   by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the
>   delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame
>   properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

selected_index= indexPath.row;
[tableView reloadData];

}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)

 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {

[view removeFromSuperview];

}

if(indexPath.row==selected_index)

{

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}

else

{

 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}

}
```